# Простой сервлет с кнопкой

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat, сервлеты

Сервлет сделан на Intellij IDEA и TomCat. Нужно, чтоб после нажатия на кнопочку Show text ниже нее появлялся текст. Не могу найти решение. Помогите...

```java
package test;
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

 
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Servlet Get</h1>");
        out.println("<br><br><br>");
        out.println("<p align=center><input type=submit value='Show text' /></p>");
        out.println("</form>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
 
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
           version="3.0">
 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1. По нажатию на кнопку отправлять форму на сервер, в качестве `action` для формы укажите эту же страницу, но с произвольным параметром ('action="/?show_text"'), в сервлете сделать условный вывод текста между `out.println("</form>");` и `out.println("</body>");` если `request.getParameter("show_text") != null`.

Вариант 2. Выводить текст по клику по кнопке средствами javascript без похода на сервер.